# ng2-table body columns not aligned

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am using [ng2-table](http://valor-software.com/ng2-table/) for my angular2 tables. 
I want a bordered table.
I need to draw my body rows (because sometimes it has checkbox, buttons etc)
So I can't use the syntax:

```
template: `<ng-table [config]="config" [columns]="columns" [rows]="rows" > </ng-table>`
```

So I am trying to use this (simplified) syntax:

```
template: `<ng-table [config]="config" [columns]="columns"> </ng-table>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody> 
    <tr *ngFor="let row of rows"> 
        <td *ngFor="let column of columns">
                {{row[column["name"]]}}
        </td>
     </tr> </tbody>
</table>
  `
```

The problem is that with this syntax the columns are not aligned. 
How can I draw my own body rows with aligned columns?

Please see a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/oAucMyQc4r4AKP8CdeaS?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the table tag from your component html template, and add rows property to ng-table tag:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'device-overview',
 // aligned columns template
 //template: `<ng-table [config]="config" [columns]="columns" [rows]="rows" > </ng-table>`

 // Not aligned columns template
  template: `<ng-table [config]="config" [columns]="columns" [rows]="rows"> </ng-table>`

})
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/MfQwqTWbTX6Pdr4WIrO9?p=preview

Comment: that is exactly what I said is working in the first template the problem is that if I want one column to have a checkbox I can't use:template: <ng-table [config]="config" [columns]="columns" [rows]="rows" > </ng-table>  but need to use write the table body myself.